# image not add on toolbar of the activity which contain tab fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am making a android app in my app there is one activity which name is Mobilerecharge activity in that activity i added three tab fragment.

my question is that when i add code for the image on toolbar it not work 
my when i debug it then image button id got null so because of that my app crash .

image on toolbar  code in Mobilerecharge activity

```
private void setupToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ImageButton btnCart = (ImageButton) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.btn_cart);
    btnCart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

this is my xml file code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    style="@style/DarkToolbar">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_cart"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/forty_dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

mobile recharge ativity xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            style="@style/DarkToolbar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

in the same activity i add three fragments so that i want that image on each fragment on tollbar

when i debug the code `ImageButton btnCart = (ImageButton) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.btn_cart);` here it will  `null` for `btn_cart`

i think it will not get the id of cart button but when i use this code for  my main activity it will show cart image on toolbar. but not in this  `Mobilerecharge activity` my `btn_cart` is located in my Toolbar xml file 
so please any one tell me how i add image on toolbar to the activity which contain tab fragments.

Comment: show your xml file ? how you adding button in toolbar?

Comment: <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_cart"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/forty_dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

Comment: better you edit in question with proper format

Comment: i added xml layout code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
ImageButton btnCart = (ImageButton) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.btn_cart);
```

with

```
ImageButton btnCart = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_cart);
```

because it is already in same activity

edit

as your xml code there is already a toolbar so you don't need to add another tool bar just copy imagebutton toobar in your xml file as below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            style="@style/DarkToolbar"><ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_cart"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/forty_dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: btn_cart is in Toolbar Xml file then how i get it with 
ImageButton btnCart = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_cart); this

Comment: your tool bar must be include in activity xml and have to set it runtime as action bar setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: i call btn_cart in main activity with 
ImageButton btnCart = (ImageButton) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.btn_cart);
and it work fine but not get that id on this activity.

Comment: you have to include toobar xml in your activity xml

Comment: show your activity xml and do u want toolbar as action bar or anything else you are trying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145048/discussion-between-pavan-and-kunal-nikam).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you saved the Toolbar layout as "toolbar.xml"

Now in your mobilerecharge activity xml layout just include the layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now inside your activity class you can refer it like you did.

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ImageButton btnCart = (ImageButton) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.btn_cart);
```